# Python pathos.multiprocessing ProcessingPool. Why the pools exchange information?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

**Intro**

I have a large amount of data on which specific calculations need to be performed. Unfortunately if I run the calculations one after another the whole process would take a day. This is why I use pathos.multiprocessing ProcessingPool on a machine with 32 CPUs. In that way the process takes about 30 minutes.

**Issue**

The expected behaviour is all calculations to run in parallel and to be completely independent from each other. What I noticed is that this is true for a small number of calculations (e.g. 40) but if I increase the number to 90 the data gets mixed. It seems like the processes "communicate" with each other...in other words somehow they have access to the same variables.

**Question**

Any idea what is going on?

Helpful link: https://pathos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pathos.html

**Code**

The code below is a simplified version of what I have on my machine but the idea is the same. So, here is the code:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool, cpu_count

class TestMultiprocessing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0

    def do_something(self, args):
        for arg in args:
            self.number += arg
        return self.number

    def run(self):
        # Generate a big list
        l = []
        for i in range(0, 100):
            l.append([1,2,3])

        pool = ProcessingPool(cpu_count())
        results = pool.imap(self.do_something, l)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool.clear()
        results = list(results)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

tm = TestMultiprocessing()
tm.run()
```

**Update**

I can't show example code because it is confidential but I can give a short explanation about how the code works.

There is a CSV file containing a few thousand lines of data (~80 000 lines). The code I wrote has to run 800 tasks each performing specific calculations taking the data from the CSV file.

The machine has N CPUs and therefore Pathos breaks down all 800 tasks to M groups each containing N tasks (If the number of CPUs is even M * N = 800). Pathos creates N pools performing the required calculations in parallel. When the calculations complete each pool generates a list of dictionaries and continue with the next group of tasks - repeating that process M times.

Each dictionary from the list contains a unique key corresponding to the number of the task which can be from 1 to 800. In that way I can check if Pool X generates dictionaries related to task X (e.g. 103). The expectation is the results generated by Pool X to contain only key X.

It is important to mention that the above process consumes most of the memory of the machine!

After detailed observation of the generated results I noticed the following. If I run N tasks (e.g. 4 tasks corresponding to a machine with 4 CPUs), each list of dictionaries contains keys corresponding to the particular task. For instance, pool X generates a list of dictionaries with keys X.

BUT if I run more than N tasks, dictionaries corresponding to a task greater than N, contain data from previous tasks. For instance, pool Y generates a list of dictionaries with keys Y, X and so on.

My conclusion is that pool X does not clear the data (memory) from the previous calculations and the next task inherit the data from the previous one.

**Solution**

Even though I use pool.clear() that didn't help me to resolve the issue. The temporary solution I found is the following.

I break down "manually" the tasks to groups.

```
import numpy as np
import math

# Get the number of CPUs
cpus = cpu_count()

# Check how many groups of tasks we have to run
chunks = math.ceil(len(l)/cpus)

# Break down the list of tasks to chunks/groups
l_chunks = np.array_split(l, chunks)

# Loop the chunks
for l_chunk in l_chunks:
    pool = ProcessingPool(cpus)
    results = pool.imap(self.do_something, l_chunk.tolist())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.clear()
    results = list(results)
    
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Well, you are using shared state by initializing the class before multiprocessing forks off...

Comment: You say the processes communicate. Show why you think so. In other words, make a proper [mcve].

Comment: (By the way, is there a reason you'd need `pathos` instead of the built-in `multiprocessing` package?)

Comment: @AKX What changes should I make to avoid the shared state? Thanks! 

The reason I use pathos is because I had issues with pickle. I have to think what was the exact issue. It was long time ago.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can't show an example but I can explain.

There is a CSV file containing a few thousand lines of data. I run approximately 800 tasks in parallel. Each task loads the data from the CSV file and performs different operations. 

Each completed task generates a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains data which is a result of the calculations. Also, the dictionary contains a unique key identifying the process that performed the calculations.

The expectation is pool X to generate list of dictionaries each having key X. This is true if I run small number of tasks.

Comment: I don't know the `pathos` implementation, but I'd guess this is a chunking issue. If the data is being sent in chunks larger than one, the same bound method will be used to process each of item within a chunk, giving it a chance to update the instance's attributes more than once.

Comment: @AKX I tried that one "Well, you are using shared state by initializing the class before multiprocessing forks off...". I init the variable self.number = 0 inside do_something method but the data is still shuffled.

Comment: I'm the pathos author.  It's unclear what you are seeing from your question, and even your comment. It would be better to see an example.  However, one thing to note is that `pathos` uses pool "singletons", by default... so if you create two `ProcessPools` with the same arguments, they are actually the same pool.  You can clear the singleton with `ProcessPool().clear()`.  Alternately, you can just use `pathos.pools._ProcessPool`, which gives you the same behavior and from `multiprocessing`, but with better pickling.  If either of those don't work for you, please create a GitHub ticket.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns  please check the update above - sections Update and Solution. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution looks as expected.  As I mentioned, `pathos` treats a `Pool` as a singleton... so if you have N Pools, they are actually just handles to the same pool instance.  If you use `clear`, it deletes the singleton, and thus behavior becomes more like you have N pool instances.  If you don't like that behavior, then you can use the `pathos.pools` that begin with an `_`.  It is possible to have runaway memory use if you are creating a bunch of pool handles, and not using `clear`.